# C++ Program executes completely, but breaks at the end?

Tags: c++

I was writing a simple application in c++, designed to calculate frequencies of sums (i.e. when you roll dice). The program runs through completely, it even produces the correct results, but at the very end of it's execution Windows tells me that the program stopped working.

I am using Dev-Cpp 5.11 with the TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32-bit release compiler to create and compile the code that follows.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

const int   int_min = numeric_limits<int>::min(),
            int_max = numeric_limits<int>::max();

int getint(string ln, int lower, int upper){
    int input = 0;
    cout << ln; 
    if(cin >> input && input >= lower && input <= upper){   
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80,'\n');        
    }else{
        cout << "ERR:\tINVALID\nDesc:\t";
        if(cin.good() && (input <= lower || input >= upper))
            cout << "OUT OF BOUNDS [" << lower << " <= val <= " << upper << "]";    
        else
            cout << "NAN";  
        cout << "\n\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80,'\n');
        return getint(ln,lower,upper);
    }
    return input;
}

int main(){
    int
            n = getint("Input(n) > ",1,int_max),
            a = getint("Input(a) > ",0,int_max),
            b = getint("Input(b) > ",a,int_max),
            r = b - a + 1,
            t = n * (r - 1) + 1;
    int
            pos = 0,
            sum = 0,
            val[n],
            frq[t];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        val[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        frq[i] = 0;
    while(pos < n){
        pos = 0;
        sum = 0;                
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += val[i];      
        frq[sum]++;
        val[pos]++;
        while(val[pos] >= r){
            val[pos++] = 0;
            if(pos <= n - 1)
                val[pos]++;                 
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        cout << "frq(" << i + n << ")\t|\t" << frq[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Warning: you are using variable length arrays (`val[n]` and `frq[t]`). These are non-standard syntax and prone to causing stack overflows.

Comment: Also note: using an alphabet soup variable naming scheme is a disincentive to people trying to debug your code. Adios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop `while(val[pos] >= r){...` may keep looping until `pos` has well exceeded `n`, which is the size of `val[]`, thus writing zeros past the end of the array.  That's disastrous.  You need to do something like `while(pos < n && val[pos] >= r){...`

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you. That does leave one question however, if the while loop was causing the issue, then why doesn't Windows detect the error until after execution is complete?

Comment: Because windows is not constantly checking your program to make sure that it is running correctly.  Your array resides in the stack, so you are probably ruining your stack frame, which contains the return address to which your `main()` function will return to the operating system.  So, it is only when `main()` returns that the whole thing goes haywire.